# ICollection[] in method signature

Tags: c#, signature

I have the following code. Why it always goes to  "take(ICollection a)" method? I think the object it self should be LinkedList or HashSet, so it should be calling the other two take method.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();

        ICollection<String>[] ary = { new LinkedList<String>(), new HashSet<String>() };

        foreach (ICollection<String> a in ary)
        {
            p.take(a);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ary.Length; i++)
        {
            p.take(ary[i]);
        }
    }


    public void take(HashSet<String> a)
    { }

    public void take(LinkedList<String> a)
    {}

    public void take(ICollection<string> a)
    { }
}
```

Comment: And why is this tagged Java?

Comment: `a` is an `ICollection`  Why would you expect a dynamic dispatch?  The method to call is determined at compile time.

Comment: @RohitJain Java and C# behaves the same, that is why I tagged Java as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method dispatching is done based on the variable type, not the runtime type.  This is covered in detail in the C# language specification, 7.5.3 (Overload Resolution) - nowhere within that entire section is there a suggestion that the *runtime type* of a variable is used.  The dispatching is handled by the compiler, based on the "argument expression":

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument expressions { E1, E2, ..., EN } and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types { P1, P2, ..., PN } and { Q1, Q2, ..., QN }, MP is defined to be a better function member than MQ if
>
> • for each argument, the implicit conversion from EX to QX is not better than the implicit conversion from EX to PX, and
>
> • for at least one argument, the conversion from EX to PX is better than the conversion from EX to QX.

If you want it to dynamic dispatch, you can do it via `dynamic`:

```
 foreach (ICollection<String> a in ary)
 {
     dynamic o = a;
     p.take(o);
 }
```

Or, the more shorter form:

```
 foreach (dynamic a in ary)
 {
     p.take(a);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Reed. How did you find this information? This is actually an interview question. For the problems in some interview questions, I never seen them happen in my work. I am so amazed you guys can point to the right place so quickly. Why is it?

Comment: @Helic Its mostly learning enough to know what to search for - you have to know exactly where to look or what to search, then it's easy to find it.  This requires knowing your stuff, though.

Comment: is there any good learning materials for this types of questiions? I am so frustrated by these questions because I never had a chance to see them in my daily work, but they do appear in interviews. Thanks.

Comment: @Helic This is mostly understanding the language well.  C# in Depth (Jon Skeet's book) is a great resource, as is CLR via C#.

Answer (score 2):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx

And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338(v=vs.71).aspx

From MSDN:

> Given an argument list A with a set of argument types {A1, A2, ...,
>   AN} and two applicable function members MP and MQ with parameter types
>   {P1, P2, ..., PN} and {Q1, Q2, ..., QN}, MP is defined to be a better
>   function member than MQ if:
>
> - for each argument, the implicit conversion from AX to PX is not worse    than the implicit conversion from AX to QX, and
> - for at least one argument, the conversion from AX to PX is better    than the conversion from AX to QX.
>
> When performing this evaluation, if MP or MQ is applicable in its
>   expanded form, then PX or QX refers to a parameter in the expanded
>   form of the parameter list.